# Spring 4.3.0.RELEASE, Hibernate 5.0.9.Final, missing SessionFactoryImplementor.getProperties method

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-4, hibernate-5.x

I am using Spring 4.3.0.RELEASE together with Hibernate 5.0.9.Final in my app and I keep getting

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.hibernate.engine.spi.SessionFactoryImplementor.getProperties()Ljava/util/Map;
```

If I update the Hibernate 5.2.0.Final, everything works fine. It seems that Spring 4.3.0 is not compatible with Hibernate 5.0, is that correct ? I was not able to find anything about not supporting Hibernate 5.0.

In Hibernate 5.2, such method exists, in Hibernate 5.0 the method doesn't exist yet (just replace 5.2 with 5.0 in URL):
http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/javadocs/org/hibernate/engine/spi/SessionFactoryImplementor.html

I have created simple reproducer:
https://github.com/trepel/spring43-hibernate50-error

Thanks for all your replies.

Comment: See https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-14365

Comment: Thanks @M.Deinum, so it's a bug and new Jira ticket has been filed. If you create real answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is already an issue, [SPR-14365](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-14365), covering that.

Comment: I am using spring 4.3.1.RELEASE and hibernate 5.2.1.Final but still i am facing same issue.

Comment: This Jira item is closed and it sounds like it was fixed, but with the Maven artifact `org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-dependencies:1.4.2.RELEASE` which is the latest the problem still exists.