# Spring 4.3.1 + Hibernate 5.2.1 creating SessionFactoryImplementor.getProperties noSuchMethod exception

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I am aware of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37861063/spring-4-3-0-release-hibernate-5-0-9-final-missing-sessionfactoryimplementor-g) question and the Spring JIRA issue it references, however, I am using the latest versions of both Hibernate and Spring and still get the same error indicated by the stacktrace below when I run my unit tests :

```
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in file [E:\business\projects\model\build\classes\test\testContext-model-hibernate.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.hibernate.engine.spi.SessionFactoryImplementor.getProperties()Ljava/util/Properties;
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1578)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:545)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:756)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:861)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:541)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:128)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:60)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.delegateLoading(AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.java:108)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.java:251)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:98)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:116)
    ... 45 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.hibernate.engine.spi.SessionFactoryImplementor.getProperties()Ljava/util/Properties;
    at org.jadira.usertype.spi.shared.AbstractUserTypeHibernateIntegrator.integrate(AbstractUserTypeHibernateIntegrator.java:192)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:275)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:483)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:707)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:723)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBuilder.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBuilder.java:372)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:454)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:439)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1637)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1574)
    ... 60 more
```

Here's a snippet from my gradle build file containing the versions of the hibernate and spring jars I use :

```
            'org.hibernate.common:hibernate-commons-annotations:5.0.1.Final',
        'org.hibernate:hibernate-core:5.2.1.Final',
        'org.hibernate:hibernate-entitymanager:5.2.1.Final',
        'org.hibernate:hibernate-orm-modules:5.2.1.Final',
        'org.hibernate:hibernate-search:5.5.4.Final',
        'org.hibernate:hibernate-search-orm:5.5.4.Final',
        'org.hibernate:hibernate-search-engine:5.5.4.Final',
        'org.springframework.security:spring-security-core:4.1.1.RELEASE',
        'org.springframework:spring-aop:4.3.1.RELEASE',
        'org.springframework:spring-aspects:4.3.1.RELEASE',
        'org.springframework:spring-beans:4.3.1.RELEASE',
        'org.springframework:spring-context:4.3.1.RELEASE',
        'org.springframework:spring-context-support:4.3.1.RELEASE',
        'org.springframework:spring-core:4.3.1.RELEASE',
        'org.springframework:spring-expression:4.3.1.RELEASE',
        'org.springframework:spring-orm:4.3.1.RELEASE',
        'org.springframework:spring-tx:4.3.1.RELEASE',
```

Could this be caused by something else I am unaware of?

**EDIT** : added output of gradle dependencies task, test runtime lines :

```
testRuntime - Runtime dependencies for source set 'test'.
+--- commons-lang:commons-lang:2.6
+--- org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.4
+--- commons-logging:commons-logging:1.2
+--- commons-validator:commons-validator:1.5.1
|    +--- commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils:1.9.2
|    |    +--- commons-logging:commons-logging:1.1.1 -> 1.2
|    |    \--- commons-collections:commons-collections:3.2.1 -> 3.2.2
|    +--- commons-digester:commons-digester:1.8.1
|    +--- commons-logging:commons-logging:1.2
|    \--- commons-collections:commons-collections:3.2.2
+--- javax.mail:javax.mail-api:1.5.5
+--- joda-time:joda-time:2.9.4
+--- net.sf.dozer:dozer:5.5.1
|    +--- commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils:1.9.1 -> 1.9.2 (*)
|    +--- org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.2.1 -> 3.4
|    +--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.5 -> 1.7.21
|    \--- org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:1.7.5
|         \--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.5 -> 1.7.21
+--- net.sf.dozer:dozer-spring:5.5.1
+--- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-core:2.6.2
|    \--- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:2.6.2
+--- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-1.2-api:2.6.2
|    +--- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:2.6.2
|    \--- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-core:2.6.2 (*)
+--- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:2.6.2
+--- org.apache.poi:poi-ooxml:3.14
|    +--- org.apache.poi:poi:3.14
|    |    \--- commons-codec:commons-codec:1.10
|    +--- org.apache.poi:poi-ooxml-schemas:3.14
|    |    \--- org.apache.xmlbeans:xmlbeans:2.6.0
|    |         \--- stax:stax-api:1.0.1
|    \--- com.github.virtuald:curvesapi:1.03
+--- org.apache.poi:poi-ooxml-schemas:3.14 (*)
+--- org.apache.velocity:velocity:1.7
|    +--- commons-collections:commons-collections:3.2.1 -> 3.2.2
|    \--- commons-lang:commons-lang:2.4 -> 2.6
+--- org.freemarker:freemarker:2.3.23
+--- org.jadira.usertype:usertype.core:5.0.0.GA
|    +--- org.hibernate:hibernate-entitymanager:5.0.1.Final -> 5.2.1.Final
|    |    +--- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:3.3.0.Final
|    |    +--- org.hibernate:hibernate-core:5.2.1.Final
|    |    |    +--- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:3.3.0.Final
|    |    |    +--- org.hibernate.javax.persistence:hibernate-jpa-2.1-api:1.0.0.Final
|    |    |    +--- org.javassist:javassist:3.20.0-GA
|    |    |    +--- antlr:antlr:2.7.7
|    |    |    +--- org.apache.geronimo.specs:geronimo-jta_1.1_spec:1.1.1
|    |    |    +--- org.jboss:jandex:2.0.0.Final
|    |    |    +--- com.fasterxml:classmate:1.3.0
|    |    |    +--- dom4j:dom4j:1.6.1
|    |    |    +--- org.hibernate.common:hibernate-commons-annotations:5.0.1.Final
|    |    |    |    \--- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:3.3.0.Final
|    |    |    \--- javax.enterprise:cdi-api:1.1-PFD
|    |    |         +--- javax.el:el-api:2.2
|    |    |         +--- org.jboss.spec.javax.interceptor:jboss-interceptors-api_1.1_spec:1.0.0.Beta1
|    |    |         +--- javax.annotation:jsr250-api:1.0
|    |    |         \--- javax.inject:javax.inject:1
|    |    +--- dom4j:dom4j:1.6.1
|    |    +--- org.hibernate.common:hibernate-commons-annotations:5.0.1.Final (*)
|    |    +--- org.hibernate.javax.persistence:hibernate-jpa-2.1-api:1.0.0.Final
|    |    +--- org.javassist:javassist:3.20.0-GA
|    |    \--- org.apache.geronimo.specs:geronimo-jta_1.1_spec:1.1.1
|    +--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.12 -> 1.7.21
|    \--- org.jadira.usertype:usertype.spi:5.0.0.GA
|         \--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.12 -> 1.7.21
+--- org.ostermiller:utils:1.07.00
+--- org.postgresql:postgresql:9.4.1209.jre7
+--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.21
+--- org.hibernate.common:hibernate-commons-annotations:5.0.1.Final (*)
+--- org.hibernate:hibernate-core:5.2.1.Final (*)
+--- org.hibernate:hibernate-entitymanager:5.2.1.Final (*)
+--- org.hibernate:hibernate-orm-modules:5.2.1.Final
+--- org.hibernate:hibernate-search:5.5.4.Final
|    \--- org.hibernate:hibernate-search-orm:5.5.4.Final
|         +--- org.hibernate:hibernate-search-engine:5.5.4.Final
|         |    +--- org.hibernate.common:hibernate-commons-annotations:5.0.1.Final (*)
|         |    +--- org.apache.lucene:lucene-core:5.3.1
|         |    +--- org.apache.lucene:lucene-backward-codecs:5.3.1
|         |    |    \--- org.apache.lucene:lucene-core:5.3.1
|         |    +--- org.apache.lucene:lucene-misc:5.3.1
|         |    |    \--- org.apache.lucene:lucene-core:5.3.1
|         |    +--- org.apache.lucene:lucene-analyzers-common:5.3.1
|         |    |    \--- org.apache.lucene:lucene-core:5.3.1
|         |    +--- org.apache.lucene:lucene-facet:5.3.1
|         |    |    +--- org.apache.lucene:lucene-core:5.3.1
|         |    |    \--- org.apache.lucene:lucene-queries:5.3.1
|         |    \--- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:3.3.0.Final
|         \--- org.hibernate:hibernate-core:5.0.9.Final -> 5.2.1.Final (*)
+--- org.hibernate:hibernate-search-orm:5.5.4.Final (*)
+--- org.hibernate:hibernate-search-engine:5.5.4.Final (*)
+--- org.springframework.security:spring-security-core:4.1.1.RELEASE
|    +--- aopalliance:aopalliance:1.0
|    +--- org.springframework:spring-aop:4.3.1.RELEASE
|    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-beans:4.3.1.RELEASE
|    |    |    \--- org.springframework:spring-core:4.3.1.RELEASE
|    |    |         \--- commons-logging:commons-logging:1.2
|    |    \--- org.springframework:spring-core:4.3.1.RELEASE (*)
|    +--- org.springframework:spring-beans:4.3.1.RELEASE (*)
|    +--- org.springframework:spring-context:4.3.1.RELEASE
|    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-aop:4.3.1.RELEASE (*)
|    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-beans:4.3.1.RELEASE (*)
|    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-core:4.3.1.RELEASE (*)
|    |    \--- org.springframework:spring-expression:4.3.1.RELEASE
|    |         \--- org.springframework:spring-core:4.3.1.RELEASE (*)
|    +--- org.springframework:spring-core:4.3.1.RELEASE (*)
|    \--- org.springframework:spring-expression:4.3.1.RELEASE (*)
+--- org.springframework:spring-aop:4.3.1.RELEASE (*)
+--- org.springframework:spring-aspects:4.3.1.RELEASE
|    \--- org.aspectj:aspectjweaver:1.8.9
+--- org.springframework:spring-beans:4.3.1.RELEASE (*)
+--- org.springframework:spring-context:4.3.1.RELEASE (*)
+--- org.springframework:spring-context-support:4.3.1.RELEASE
|    +--- org.springframework:spring-beans:4.3.1.RELEASE (*)
|    +--- org.springframework:spring-context:4.3.1.RELEASE (*)
|    \--- org.springframework:spring-core:4.3.1.RELEASE (*)
+--- org.springframework:spring-core:4.3.1.RELEASE (*)
+--- org.springframework:spring-expression:4.3.1.RELEASE (*)
+--- org.springframework:spring-orm:4.3.1.RELEASE
|    +--- org.springframework:spring-beans:4.3.1.RELEASE (*)
|    +--- org.springframework:spring-core:4.3.1.RELEASE (*)
|    +--- org.springframework:spring-jdbc:4.3.1.RELEASE
|    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-beans:4.3.1.RELEASE (*)
|    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-core:4.3.1.RELEASE (*)
|    |    \--- org.springframework:spring-tx:4.3.1.RELEASE
|    |         +--- org.springframework:spring-beans:4.3.1.RELEASE (*)
|    |         \--- org.springframework:spring-core:4.3.1.RELEASE (*)
|    \--- org.springframework:spring-tx:4.3.1.RELEASE (*)
+--- org.springframework:spring-tx:4.3.1.RELEASE (*)
+--- com.yobu:yobu-mi:
+--- junit:junit:4.12
|    \--- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:1.3
+--- org.springframework:spring-test:4.3.1.RELEASE
|    \--- org.springframework:spring-core:4.3.1.RELEASE (*)
\--- org.mockito:mockito-all:2.0.2-beta

(*) - dependencies omitted (listed previously)

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
```

Comment: Check gradle dependency tree using "gradle dependencies" command, maybe dependencies are not resolved as you expect.  Another alternative can use decompiler (i.e. Idea has really nice one) and check  SessionFactoryImplementor to validate version.

Comment: Thanks, I added the output for the runtime dependencies for the tests. Could it be that the dependency tree for jadira.usertype referencing hibernate 5.0.1 version jars be the cause?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The Jadira library is not compatible with Hibernate 5.2.  The `getProperties` method was removed from the `SessionFactoryImplementor` interface in that release.

You should be able to revert to the Hibernate 5.1.x release stream and maintain compatibility perhaps?

Answer (score 5):

New version of Jadira was released in Aug, `6.0.0.GA` - solved the problem.

Answer (score 2):

check whether more than one jar having **EntityManagerFactory** interfaces, if yes remove the jar which is don't have getProperties method.

**getProperties** is not direct method of **SessionFactoryImplementor**. it's parent interface **EntityManagerFactory** method, which is extended like follows

**SessionFactoryImplementor extends SessionFactory


SessionFactory extends EntityManagerFactory 


EntityManagerFactory interface have getProperties method**

in my case i found two jars have this interface

WEB-INF/lib/**hibernate-jpa-2.1-api-1.0.0.Final.jar**

WEB-INF/lib/**persistence-api-1.0.jar**

i checked the interfaces in both jars where hibernate-jpa-2.1-api-1.0.0.Final jar have getProperties method in EntityManagerFactory interface 

persistence-api-1.0 jar dont have getProperties method in EntityManagerFactory interface.

so i **removed persistence-api-1.0.jar** and now working fine.

Comment: Also check hibernate-jpamodelgen version