# Hibernate 5.2.7 - java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.hibernate.engine.spi.SessionFactoryImplementor.getProperties()Ljava/util/Map;

Tags: java, hibernate, nosuchmethoderror

while using Hibernate 5.2.7 in a Gradle Java Project to connect to a MariaDB 10.1.19, I am getting an `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.hibernate.engine.spi.SessionFactoryImplementor.getProperties()Ljava/util/Map;`

The complete stacktrace

```
 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.hibernate.engine.spi.SessionFactoryImplementor.getProperties()Ljava/util/Map;
at org.hibernate.internal.CacheImpl.<init>(CacheImpl.java:71)
at org.hibernate.engine.spi.CacheInitiator.initiateService(CacheInitiator.java:28)
at org.hibernate.engine.spi.CacheInitiator.initiateService(CacheInitiator.java:20)
at org.hibernate.service.internal.SessionFactoryServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(SessionFactoryServiceRegistryImpl.java:58)
at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:259)
at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:233)
at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:210)
at org.hibernate.service.internal.SessionFactoryServiceRegistryImpl.getService(SessionFactoryServiceRegistryImpl.java:77)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:240)
at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:445)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:710)
at quantitativeAnalysis.backend.dataCollector.dataCollectorManager.createFactory(dataCollectorManager.java:280)
at quantitativeAnalysis.volatilityAnalyzer.volatilityDynamicImpl.openInstance(volatilityDynamicImpl.java:18)
at frontend.MainFrame.main(MainFrame.java:96)
```

I have tried several approaches (other Hibernate Versions **5.2.6** and **5.2.3**) and searched the internet for help, but none of the suggestions worked.

The Exception occur here:

```
    Configuration configuration = new Configuration().configure();

    StandardServiceRegistryBuilder ssrb = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(configuration.getProperties());
    try{
        factory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(ssrb.build());
    }catch(Exception ex){
    System.err.println("Failed to configure Sessionfactory");
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

I have also tried the following code leading to the same result:

```
    final StandardServiceRegistry registry = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder()
    .configure() // configures settings from hibernate.cfg.xml
    .build();

try {
    factory = new MetadataSources(registry).buildMetadata().buildSessionFactory();
    }catch(Exception ex){
    System.err.println("Failed to configure Sessionfactory");
    ex.printStackTrace();
    }
```

My hibernate.cfg.xml looks like this

```
<session-factory>

    <!-- Database connection settings -->
    <!-- <property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property> -->
    <property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver</property>        
    <property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3307/VolatilityData</property>
    <property name="connection.username">XXX</property>
    <property name="connection.password">XXX</property>
    <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect</property>


    <!--  -->
    <property name="hbm2dll.auto">create</property>

    <!-- mapping content -->
    <mapping resource="resources/BitcoinDaysDestroyed.hbm.xml"/>
    <mapping resource="resources/BitcoinPrice.hbm.xml"/>
    <mapping resource="resources/BitcoinTransactions.hbm.xml"/>

</session-factory>
```

The jars I include with Gradle are the following:

```
// Apply the java plugin to add support for Java
apply plugin: 'java'

// In this section you declare where to find the dependencies of your   project
repositories {
// Use jcenter for resolving your dependencies.
// You can declare any Maven/Ivy/file repository here.
//jcenter()
mavenCentral()

maven {
url "https://maven.elasticsearch.org/releases"
  }
}

dependencies {
// The production code uses Guava
compile 'com.google.guava:guava:20.0'

//QuantitativeAnalysis

// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.toedter/jcalendar
compile group: 'com.toedter', name: 'jcalendar', version: '1.4'

// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.persistence/persistence-api
compile group: 'javax.persistence', name: 'persistence-api', version: '1.0.2'

// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.googlecode.json-simple/json-simple
compile group: 'com.googlecode.json-simple', name: 'json-simple', version: '1.1.1'

// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpclient
compile group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents', name: 'httpclient', version: '4.5.2'

// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpcore
compile group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents', name: 'httpcore', version: '4.4.5'

// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-core
//compile group: 'org.hibernate', name: 'hibernate-core', version: '5.2.6.Final'

//antlr-2.7.7.jar, compiled from src
compile files('libs/antlr-2.7.7.jar')

//classmate-1.3.0.jar, compiled from src
compile files('libs/classmate-1.3.0.jar')

//dom4j-1.6.1.jar, compiled from src
compile files('libs/dom4j-1.6.1.jar')

//antlr-2.7.7.jar, compiled from src
compile files('libs/geronimo-jta_1.1_spec-1.1.1.jar')

//jandex-2.0.3.Final.jar, compiled from src
compile files('libs/jandex-2.0.3.Final.jar')

//javassist-3.20.0-GA.jar, compiled from src
compile files('libs/javassist-3.20.0-GA.jar')

//jboss-logging-3.3.0.Final.jar, compiled from src
compile files('libs/jboss-logging-3.3.0.Final.jar')

//hibernate-commons-annotations-5.0.1.Final.jar, compiled from src
compile files('libs/hibernate-commons-annotations-5.0.1.Final.jar')

//hibernate-jpa-2.1-api-1.0.0.Final.jar, compiled from src
compile files('libs/hibernate-jpa-2.1-api-1.0.0.Final.jar')

//hibernate-core-5.2.7.Final.jar, compiled from src
compile files('libs/hibernate-core-5.2.7.Final.jar')

//c3p0-0.9.5.2, compiled from src
compile files('libs/c3p0-0.9.5.2.jar')

//hibernate-c3p0-5.2.7.Final.jar, compiled from src
compile files('libs/hibernate-c3p0-5.2.7.Final.jar')

//mchange-commons-java-0.2.11.jar, compiled from src
compile files('libs/mchange-commons-java-0.2.11.jar')

// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java
compile group: 'mysql', name: 'mysql-connector-java', version: '6.0.5'

//QualitatitveAnalysis

// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/log4j/log4j
compile group: 'log4j', name: 'log4j', version: '1.2.17'

// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.elasticsearch/elasticsearch
compile group: 'org.elasticsearch', name: 'elasticsearch', version: '2.1.0'

// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.elasticsearch.plugin/shield
compile group: 'org.elasticsearch.plugin', name: 'shield', version: '2.1.0'

// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.code.gson/gson
compile group: 'com.google.code.gson', name: 'gson', version: '2.8.0'

// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.twitter4j/twitter4j-core
compile group: 'org.twitter4j', name: 'twitter4j-core', version: '4.0.6'

// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.json/javax.json-api
compile group: 'javax.json', name: 'javax.json-api', version: '1.0'

//jReddit Jar, compiled from src
compile files('libs/jReddit-1.0.4-SNAPSHOT.jar')

// Use JUnit test framework
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

Any help or advice is highly appreciated

Comment: Looks like incompatible versions of hibernate and an other lib. Please add the complete stacktrace

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37861063/spring-4-3-0-release-hibernate-5-0-9-final-missing-sessionfactoryimplementor-g  may help you

Comment: Thanks for your replies, I have added the complete stacktrace.

I have seen the other question on stackoverflow, but they use Spring, which I do not use for my Java application.

Answer (score 12):

This problem is caused by having an old, incompatible copy of the JPA API on the classpath.

Specifically:

- javax.persistence:persistence-api:1.0.2

Conflicts with the right version of the JPA 2.1 API:

- org.hibernate.javax.persistence:hibernate-jpa-2.1-api:1.0.0.Final

Unfortunately Maven 3 is still unable to handle re-distributions of the same artifacts, which are sometimes necessary.

Comment: See also [Where can I find a JPA2 Maven dependency?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6836772/772981)

Comment: I mentioned it in my answer: org.hibernate.javax.persistence:hibernate-jpa-2.1-api:1.0.0.Final

Comment: But it's also possible to get JPA2 without `org.hibernate`.

Comment: sure, feel free to search for another one, but the API is the same for all distributions as it's defined by the JPA standard.

Answer (score 6):

What version of the Gradle do you have?

I ask, because I have the same error which occurs after upgrade Gradle from `3.5` to `4.3`. The same Hibernate version (`5.2.9`), the same Spring Boot (`1.5.8`) but in Gradle `3.5.` - OK, `4.3` fail.

I've tested and latest version working fine was for me `3.5.1`. I've tested versions from `4.0` to `4.4-rc-6` (latest at this moment).

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-3.5.1-all.zip
```

Comment: Same exact issue. How did you fix it?

Comment: @RavishBhagdev See this answer for instructions on fixing the problem: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51791110/965150