# Spring Test succeed on eclipse but fail on gradle build

Tags: java, spring, eclipse, gradle, build.gradle

I don't know why but my spring boot test succeed in eclipse when running it as junit, but then fail when I execute the command:

```
gradle clean build
```

Here is my build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        springBootVersion = '1.5.8.RELEASE'
    }
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8

jar {
    baseName = rootProject.name
    version =  project.version
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}



dependencies {
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa')
    compile('org.springframework:spring-jdbc')
    compile('mysql:mysql-connector-java')
    compile('javax.validation:validation-api')
    compile('org.hibernate:hibernate-core:5.2.2.Final')
    compile('org.hibernate:hibernate-tools:5.2.0.Final')
    testCompile('com.h2database:h2:1.4.196')
    testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
    testCompile('org.springframework.security:spring-security-test')

}
```

All my test fails once I run the gradle command, for various reasons, mainly not being able to create beans and autowire them to the test classes.

Here is a test example:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = Application.class)
@DataJpaTest
@ActiveProfiles("test")
public class IEmployeeRepositoryTest {

@Autowired
private TestEntityManager entityManager;

@Autowired
private IEmployeeRepository employeRepository;
```

And this is the reason why the build/test fails:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' 
defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is 
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.hibernate.engine.spi.SessionFactoryImplementor.getProperties()Ljava/util/Properties;
```

I appreciate all the help I can get, I've been stuck on this for hours.

**UPDATE**
This is the output of  my gradle dependencies:
[Image to gradle dependencies](https://i.stack.imgur.com/twaq5.png)

I should also mention that project structure is this:

```
src
---main
-----java
-----resources
------application.yml
------schema.sql
---test
-----java
-----resources
------application-test.yml
------schema-test.sql
```

Comment: Can you add the result of "gradle dependencies" ?

Comment: can you please elaborate? what do you mean by gradle dependencies?

Comment: dependencies is a gradle target, like "gradle build". "gradle dependencies" displays the versions of the libraries used by your project

Comment: The output is too long, are you sure you want me to post it?

Comment: In fact only the test scope is needed. It starts with testRuntime - Runtime dependencies for source set 'test'.

Comment: This is what I'm getting for that scope: 
testRuntimeOnly - Runtime only dependencies for source set 'test'. (n)
No dependencies

Comment: But you should have some dependencies ? Things like
 +--- fr.opensagres.xdocreport:fr.opensagres.xdocreport.itext.extension:1.0.3

|    \--- com.lowagie:itext:2.1.7

+--- junit:junit:4.7 -> 4.12
( Sorry no line return in comments... )

Comment: I updaded my post with a photo to the gradle dependencies

Comment: Maybe duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41761637/hibernate-5-2-7-java-lang-nosuchmethoderror-org-hibernate-engine-spi-sessionf

Answer (score 0):

I faced this scenario today, In my case, the problem was I used Java 8 JDK for the eclipse project and my Gradle was pointing to my machine JDK 11. I changed into Java 8 from Java 11 and It worked